# Write terabyte data into xml

Tags: xml, bigdata

I am thinking about data format for my project. It could grow to terabyte in the future. I just feel guilty to write such big data using xml but I couldn't really tell why not.

Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Yes. Use [`hdf5`](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/whatishdf5.html). It is exactly what you need. Just google it and you will see what I mean.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the nature of your data as well as potential use cases, otherwise it's impossible to make a suggestion. For ex, is it time series (ordered)? is it homogeneous (no new fields in the future)? how often do you need to read/write? what kind of analysis do you plan on doing with it?

Comment: I agree with @caoy, although there can be legitimate use cases, a 1TB xml file sounds quite awkward.  Have you considered alternatives like relational or nosql or graph databases?  If yes, can you explain why you think they are not the right solution in your case, and that humongous file is?

Comment: Large XML files are read-only for most practical purposes - since valid XML does not support "append" (due to need of closing tag) adding/changing anything requires complete re-creation of the file (assuming you are not inventing your own API to read/write XML).

Comment: You got it. This XML is ready only for passing results to another party. I do not plan to change or query it at all. Maybe store it on hard drive as archive.

Answer (score 1):

You said in your question

> Do you have any other suggestions?

I would recommend that you look at the [HDF5 technologies for storing large and complex data](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/whatishdf5.html). It it a format that is well established in the scientific computing community and industry (including NCSA, NASA, Northrop Grumman, Boeing, Caterpillar, and General Electric). Python, IDL and Matlab all have excellent libraries / modules / functions for interacting with these files, and software is (freely) available on many OS platforms to incorporate the technology into your product. It handles all data types, but since it's a binary data format it allows for far greater compression than the equivalent XML.

From the above link:

> The HDF5 technology suite includes:
>
> - A versatile data model that can **represent very complex data objects**
>   and a wide variety of metadata. 
> - A **completely portable file format** with
>   **no limit on the number or size of data objects** in the collection.
> - A
>   software library that runs on a range of computational platforms, from
>   laptops to massively parallel systems, and implements a high-level API
>   with C, C++, Fortran 90, and Java interfaces.
> - A rich set of integrated
>   performance features that allow for **access time and storage space
>   optimizations**.
> - Tools and applications for managing, manipulating,
>   viewing, and analyzing the data in the collection.

You can find more information at http://www.hdfgroup.org/about/HDF5Brochure_2012.pdf

*disclaimer* I am not associated with the HDF5 Group; but my company does use their technologies for some of our most demanding data storage applications.

We have pretty large files (well in excess of a TB of data, but admittedly not all stored in a single file; since a lot of our data is "similar, but different" - think "calibration files for each of 200 identical instruments" to get the idea -, we have a database that drives the top level "in what file do we look for data" decision, then the individual HDF5 file for a highly structured, compressed, and high performance representation of that data.)

Bottom line:

1. HDF5 is a good alternative to XML for storing self-describing complex data formats
2. Unlike XML it allows for data compression (important when you have a TB)
3. I recommend that you consider whether the problem can be broken into a database + collection of smaller files.

Answer (score 0):

For anything this large, what you probably want to do is store it in an application-specific database for efficiency of access, and serialize it (or selected parts of it) to XML only when you want to exchange it with other applications.

As a compromise, you might want to look at something like DB2's "Pure XML" feature. That implements a true XML data model while taking advantage of IBM's traditional DB2 expertise in database access optimization. (Claimer: I'm with IBM, and I made some data structure suggestions which may or may not have been used in the final version of that design.)

Answer (score 0):

If you just mean as opposed to a binary file then what you're losing with XML is compression.  XML is bigger because of tagging, encoding, and escaped characters.  However, XML also communicates your data layout.  Binary doesn't.  That's what makes XML portable.  So XML isn't bigger for no reason.  It's actually doing more.

If you don't care about portability (because you control both the creating and consuming apps and don't see future needs) then binary works.  It's smaller and faster.  If you're feeling generous, document the format for future developers with something other than code.

If you don't want to lose the portability of XML but don't want a large XML files then zip them up.  It saves space at the cost of time since the data is no longer immediately usable.  This is the classic time / space trade off.

XML is neither faster nor smaller than binary.  Despite being harder on computers XML usually wins because it's easy on developers.  Developers cost employers much more than computers do.  Moores law isn't making developers cheaper.  What drives bloat isn't bits, it's bucks.

Besides traditional binary, raw xml, and zipped xml there are hybrids that try to find a balance between these three extremes.  If you go this way pick a well known one because your data is only portable while it's alive.  Pick your dependencies carefully.

Be aware that the OS will impose file size limits.  If there is a good conceptual boundary to your data use that to break it up into smaller files.

If you go with zipped xml and this is meant to be a data file for your application give it your own file extension and take care of the zipping and unzipping yourself.

If, as you say in the comments, you aren't making changes or doing queries and simply want to hand it off to something else that also isn't making changes or doing queries on it then I don't see the point of a database.

If these are to many if's then next time provide more details of your situation. :)